# Importing excel file to SQL database, how to ignore 2nd row; asp.net & C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel, import

I'm importing data in a SQL Server 2008 database from excel file where the first row is headers (HDR=1). The thing is that the second row is also kind of headers which i don't really need to be imported. So how do I ignore the second row from that excel (I guess if the first row is the headers, the actual second row in excel is first)?

In MySQL is just about saying IGNORE LINES 1 in the end of import command ... How do I do it in SQL Server?

Here is part of the code doing that:

```
 //Create Connection to Excel work book
            OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);


            //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [task_code],[status_code],[wbs] from [task$]", excelConnection);

            excelConnection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader dReader;
            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString);
            //Give your Destination table name
            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "task";
            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
            sqlBulk.Close();
```

Thanks

Comment: Read two lines from the data reader before the write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
...
OleDbDataReader dReader;
dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if( !dReader.Read() || !dReader.Read()) 
  return "No data";
SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString);
...
```

Comment: Fantastic ... I can't really understand the logic of the if statement and how come it skips the row ... but thankssssssss :)

Comment: I just found that I lose some of the rows ... Can you explain a bit more what is it supposed to check ? Thanks

Comment: Two reads in `if` user to skip first two rows, if they exists, if not - it will return

Comment: Okay but there is something wrong..it ignores the second row as well where it shouldn not! I guess if I set the HDR=No will do the trick? I need to skip the first row only (which is actually the second in excel) where the first are the headers...

Comment: To skip only one row rewrite the `if` like this: `if( !dReader.Read())`

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be to:

1. Copy the file
2. Use Office interop to delete the second line of the spreadsheet
3. Import the amended spreadsheet

To delete the line from the spreadsheet:

```
public static void DeleteRow(string pathToFile, string sheetName, string cellRef)
{
    Application app= new Application();
    Workbook  workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(pathToFile);

    for (int sheetNum = 1; sheetNum <  workbook.Sheets.Count + 1; sheetNum++)
    {
        Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[sheetNum];
        if (sheet.Name != sheetName)
        {
            continue;
        }

        Range secondRow = sheet.Range[cellRef];
        secondRow.EntireRow.Delete();

    }

    workbook.Save();
    workbook.Close();
    app.Quit();
}
```